# How to select a value from a column depending on the max value from another column

Tags: sql

I have this
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Llp.png)

that comes from

```
SELECT n.tin_max, count(n.tin_max)
AS tin_ FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tin AS tin_max, nome_cat, count(responsavel_por.tin)
FROM responsavel_por GROUP BY tin, nome_cat ORDER BY tin
) AS n GROUP BY tin_max ORDER BY tin_max;
```

and i want to select the tin_max with the max tin_ which in this case is the 2 but i dont know how to select it

Comment: Please edit your sample data as code. Provide expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do what you've asked, assuming the name of the table in your question is `foo`:

```sql
select tin_max from foo where tin_ = (select max(tin_) from foo);
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: @Alex 200 Do you need any additional help with your question?